# How to add conditions in SQL Subquery

Tags: sql, xml

I have a nested sub-query to generate XML file output results.

In the final XML results, I need to skip few elements based on conditions.

Please help how do I go about in the below scenario?

Query:

```
SELECT  InterfaceName,[Version],CreationSource,CreationTimestamp,
  (SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS BusinessUnitList,
        (SELECT  BusinessUnit.[BusinessUnit_id] AS id, 

         (SELECT  [User_id]AS id,[User_loginName] AS loginName ,[User_password] AS [password] ,[User_statusCode] AS statusCode,[User_firstName] AS firstName,[User_lastName] AS lastName ,[User_defaultLanguageName] AS defaultLanguageName,[User_forcePasswordChange] AS forcePasswordChange,

             --RoleList
                (SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS RoleList,
                    (SELECT Role_id AS id FROM #UserRole AS [Role] WHERE [Role].User_id= [User].[User_id]   FOR XML AUTO, TYPE) 
                   FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS RoleList  FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
                   ),

            --OrgList
                (SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS OrgList,
                    (SELECT [Organization_id] AS id FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS Organization  WHERE Organization.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE) 
                    FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS OrgList FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
                  ),
            --Address
                (SELECT [Address_country] AS country ,[Address_email] AS email FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS [Address] WHERE [Address].[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE) ,

            --Employee
                (SELECT [Employee_badgeNumber] AS badgeNumber,[Employee_birthDate] AS birthDate,[Employee_hireDate] AS hireDate,[Employee_seniorityDate] AS seniorityDate,[Employee_managerLevelFlag] AS managerLevelFlag,[Employee_managerClockOverridePassword]  AS managerClockOverridePassword,[Employee_punchValidation] AS punchValidation,[Employee_employeeType] AS employeeType,[Employee_schedulingTypeCode] AS schedulingTypeCode, [Employee_employeeGeneratesExceptions] AS employeeGeneratesExceptions ,[Employee_employeeGeneratesAlerts] AS employeeGeneratesAlerts ,[Employee_payrollSystemNumber] AS payrollSystemNumber ,


--AccrualConfigList
--Here need to add condition to skip this element if AccrualConfig_id is NULL

                    (SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS AccrualConfigList,
                        (SELECT [AccrualConfig_id] AS id, [AccrualConfig_start] AS start FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS AccrualConfig WHERE AccrualConfig.[User_id]= [User].[User_id]   FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
                        FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS AccrualConfigList  FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
                    ) ,

                        --Availability

                        (SELECT [Availability_minHoursPerWeek] AS minHoursPerWeek,[Availability_maxHoursPerWeek] AS maxHoursPerWeek,[Availability_maxDaysPerWeek]AS maxDaysPerWeek,[Availability_maxConsecutiveDays]AS maxConsecutiveDays,[Availability_maxConsecutiveDaysAcrossWeeks]AS maxConsecutiveDaysAcrossWeeks,[Availability_minHoursBetweenShifts]AS minHoursBetweenShifts,     [Availability_allowSplitShifts]AS allowSplitShifts FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS [Availability] WHERE [Availability].[User_id]= [User].[User_id]  FOR XML AUTO, TYPE),
                        --Job List--
                        (SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS JobList,
                      (SELECT  [Job_id] AS id, [Job_start] AS start,   
                        (SELECT  [PrimaryJobInfo_payPolicyId] AS payPolicyId,[PrimaryJobInfo_punchRuleId] AS punchRuleId,[PrimaryJobInfo_shiftStrategyId] AS shiftStrategyId,[PrimaryJobInfo_exemptFlag] AS exemptFlag,[PrimaryJobInfo_salariedFlag] AS salariedFlag,[PrimaryJobInfo_fullTimeFlag] AS fullTimeFlag FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS PrimaryJobInfo   WHERE PrimaryJobInfo.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE ) ,
                        (SELECT [JobRate_start] AS start,[JobRate_rate] AS rate FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS JobRate WHERE JobRate.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)  

                       FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS Job WHERE Job.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
                       FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS JobList WHERE JobList.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE),

                       --WorkStatusList
                       (SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS WorkStatusList,
                        (SELECT [WorkStatus_action] AS action,[WorkStatus_status] AS status,[WorkStatus_start] AS start   FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS WorkStatus WHERE WorkStatus.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)                    
                         FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS WorkStatusList WHERE WorkStatusList.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
                        )

                        --(SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS TimeoffAccrualList,
                        --(SELECT [TimeoffAccrual_PayAdjustmentID] AS payAdjustmentId,[TimeOffAccrual_EffectiveDate] AS effectiveDate, [TimeOffAccrual_Accrued] AS accrued FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS TimeoffAccrual WHERE TimeoffAccrual.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
                        -- FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS TimeoffAccrualList WHERE TimeoffAccrualList.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
                        --)

                    FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS Employee  WHERE Employee.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
                )


          FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS [User] WHERE [User].[BusinessUnit_id] = BusinessUnit.[BusinessUnit_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)

        FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS BusinessUnit WHERE BusinessUnit.[BusinessUnit_id]='10027760' GROUP BY BusinessUnit.[BusinessUnit_id]  FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)  
        FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS BusinessUnitList FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
  FROM #Document AS EnterpriseDocument FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
```

Comment: Please refer to --AccrualConfigList; need condition here

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to the needed minimum. You should remove repeated (but irrelevant) portions. poste the (reduced) output you get and what your expected output should look like. Please read [How to ask a good SQL question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056)  and [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Quick demo , null value is skipped  in `for xml auto, type`

```
with t as  (
    select 1 c1, 2 c2
    union all
    select 3, 4
    union all
    select 5, 6
)
select c1, (
        select c1, case when c2 < 6 then c2 end as c2 
        from t t2
        where t1.c1=t2.c1
        for xml auto, type) xml
from t t1 ;
```

Comment: Current Implementation

Comment: (SELECT [Employee_badgeNumber] AS badgeNumber,[Employee_birthDate] AS birthDate,[Employee_hireDate] AS hireDate,

--AccrualConfigList
(SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS AccrualConfigList,
(SELECT [AccrualConfig_id] AS id, [AccrualConfig_start] AS start FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS AccrualConfig FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS AccrualConfigList  FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
) ,
--Job List--
--SubQuery for Job List

FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS Employee  WHERE Employee.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE

Comment: (SELECT [Employee_badgeNumber] AS badgeNumber,[Employee_birthDate] AS birthDate,

--AccrualConfigList
If [AccrualConfig_id] IS NULL THEN GO TO SkipAccrual
(SELECT TOP 1 NULL AS AccrualConfigList,
(SELECT [AccrualConfig_id] AS id, [AccrualConfig_start] AS start FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS AccrualConfig FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS AccrualConfigList  FOR XML AUTO, TYPE
) ,

SkipAccrual:
--Job List--
--SubQuery for Job List
FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS Employee  WHERE Employee.[User_id]= [User].[User_id] FOR XML AUTO, TYPE

Comment: above is the expected implementation

Comment: Generally `(SELECT 
    [AccrualConfig_id] AS id, 
    [AccrualConfig_start] AS start 
   FROM [dbo].[EmployeeFeedStage] AS AccrualConfig 
   WHERE AccrualConfig.[User_id]= [User].[User_id]   
   FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)` may return multiple items . What do you mean "[AccrualConfig_id] is null", all nulls or at least one null?